# Question mark sign in terminal of Mac OS

Tags: macos, terminal

Recently I installed a theme plugin in iTerm and it looks like this on iTerm:

[image]

But in Terminal it shows like below:

[image]

I had the same issue in iterm, but after checking `Use built-in Powerline glyphs` it was solved.

Can anyone help solving this issue in terminal?

Thank You

Comment: Don't know the solution but the question mark usually means it is a font issue, i.e the font probably doesn't have a proper representation of whatever unicode right arrow is being used.

Comment: Thank you, I changed font family and it works good now 

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For future reference: Solution is to change the font!